# Doesn't load data from firestore

Tags: firebase

I have created data for firestore.But it gives empty array.And it renders two times at the one time and it gives first empty array and second is data object.I have also used useMemo.
Here is a data model of firestore:

[image: firestore data for posts]

And my code :

```
   const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
db.collection("posts").onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
  snapshot.docs.map((doc) => setPosts({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() }))
);
```

}, []);

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution. You have to temporarily push the posts to an array inside you function, and then set that array to `posts`.

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  function fetchPosts() {
    const docList = [];
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("posts")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          docList.push({
            id: doc.id
            data: doc.data()
          });
        });
        setPosts(docList);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts()
  }, [])
```